# c# VS Express 2012 console application closing instantly no matter what

Tags: c#, winforms

Recently, with the intent to prank my brother I've watched this video called the "Drunk PC": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48k9eyVsC-M

I have experience in c# and it was not hard for me to understand the code and write it. Ok, let's get to the point.

My CODE works perfectly fine and it does everything I want to (as a console application) but when I go to my project properties and change the output type to "Windows application" and run it, it closes instantly.

Those who have seen the video know that you can hide the app if you change it to a windows application.

I've tried to add: `Console.Read();` and `if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) Console.ReadLine();`, but none of this works, it just closes instantly. If the code is needed, I'll paste it here even though it's pretty long.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
using System.Drawing;

namespace DrunkPC
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Random _random = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DrunkPC Prank Application by: Cupid (get pranked bruv)");

            Thread drunkMouseThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrunkMouseThread));
            Thread drunkKeyboardThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrunkKeyboardThread));
            Thread drunkSoundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrunkSoundThread));
            Thread drunkPopupThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrunkPopupThread));

            drunkMouseThread.Start();
            drunkKeyboardThread.Start();
            drunkSoundThread.Start();
            drunkPopupThread.Start();

            Console.Read();

            drunkMouseThread.Abort();
            drunkKeyboardThread.Abort();
            drunkSoundThread.Abort();
            drunkPopupThread.Abort();
        }

        public static void DrunkMouseThread()
        {
            int moveX = 0;
            int moveY = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("DrunkMouseThread started");
            while (true)
            {
                moveX = _random.Next(20) - 10;
                moveY = _random.Next(20) - 10;
                Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(Cursor.Position.X + moveX, Cursor.Position.Y + moveY);
                Thread.Sleep(50); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes, if you create a Windows application, it doesn't attach a console. If you want a console app, why have you changed the project type to "Windows application"?

Comment: My mistake, I wrote it very sloppy.
I did create it as a console application, but to hide it, so my brother doesn't know it's running, I must change the output type to "Windows application".

Comment: Okay. So by "closes instantly" what exactly do you mean? I'd expect it to continue executing in the background. What does your code do, and what stops? I've just tried this myself, with a small app which just appends to a file once per second... it keeps going fine.

Comment: It runs for about a second and it closes showing no errors or anything.
Could it be because I'm using quite an old version of VS express 2012?

Comment: Well I suggest you post a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. I'm not going to sit through a YouTube video when the code should be in the question. And no, I doubt that it's anything to do with VS Express. I think it's more likely to be a problem in the code that we can't see.

Comment: I will add the code in a moment, please hold on.

Comment: Please note that I didn't ask for *all* the code - just a minimal (but complete) example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @CupidWupid Why don't you just edit your post and place the code in there that way? It will even keep the formatting if you use the `code` formatting.

Comment: I tried taking screenshots of the code to not make any mistakes, but it does not allow me to post more than 2 links and my code is put into 3 images, so I guess I'll have to manually edit my original post with the code.

Comment: Finished the edit, but I only added the mouse thread because I don't see the importance of copying all 4 threads that work fine.

Comment: Could that keyboard thread be "typing", providing the Console.Read with a character? Try Thread.Sleep(10000) instead and see if it does stay up for 10 seconds.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.

I tried commenting out the keyboard thread and that didn't fix the problem unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Given you have `Windows Application` as project output I'd suggest it to change main method to something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DrunkPC Prank Application by: Cupid (get pranked bruv)");

    Thread drunkMouseThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrunkMouseThread));
    Thread drunkKeyboardThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrunkMouseThread));
    Thread drunkSoundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrunkMouseThread));
    Thread drunkPopupThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DrunkMouseThread));

    drunkMouseThread.Start();
    drunkKeyboardThread.Start();
    drunkSoundThread.Start();
    drunkPopupThread.Start();

    // this one makes the trick
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Once you start the app - no window is shown, mouse goes crazy until app gets killed

Comment: First to say, sorry for the late response.
The endless while loop did make the app stay open, but it doesn't do anything now, no crazy move movements, etc..

Comment: @CupidWupid, just to confirm: is your project's Output Type set to `Windows Application`? otherwise it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add the line:

```
Console.ReadLine()
```

To the end.  It will pause until you hit enter.

Comment: That works when it is a console application, but when I change the output type to "Windows application", it doesn't work.